# Run C++ executable from php file - php file called from a HTML button clicked via web interface

Tags: php

My problem is simple, I would like to display a button on a web interface (using Flask). When the user click the button, it calls a php file which aims to execute a c++ executable.

I have done this so far:

This is my html:

```
    <form method="post" action="callmyprogram.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <p>Chose the ID you want to flash with:</p> </td> 
                <td> <input name="node_id" id="demoA" style="height:50px;"> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <p>File name:</p> </td> 
                <td> <input name="file_name" style="height:50px;"> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input id="buttonid" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="FLASH"> </td>           
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

So with the post method, when I click on the button, it is supposed to go to my `callmyprogram.php` file

Moreover, I would like to use the two inputs as arguments when I execute my executable.
On my terminal I run this for the c++ executable: `./Ex02_DriveStatus arg1 arg2` so I want my php file to execute it like that too.

arg1 is the input from `name="node_id"`
arg2 is the input from `name="file_name"`
chosen by the user

This is what I have done for the php file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $node_id = htmlentities($($_POST['node_id']);
        $file_name = htmlentities($($_POST['file_name']);
        exec("./Ex02_DriveStatus $node_id $file_name", $output);
    }
?>
```

But it gaves me a 404 error when I click on the button.

```
"POST /callmyprogram.php HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

`callmyprogram.php` and `file.html` are in the same folder

Comment: (0) Are you requesting the code from a server (i.e localhost/someFolder/somefile.html ) ?
(1) Does the php file exist in the same folder as the html file?

I am doing both and the php file's output (currently blank since my php file is empty) is displayed when the btn is clicked.

Comment: I edited my question with the right path for `callmyprogram.php` and it's still not working, still `404 error`. My html file is in `/home/test_user/Documents/flashing_testing_interface/templates/htmlfile.html`
It's still not found..

Comment: What happens when you try access '/home/test_user/Documents/flashing_testing_interface/callmyprogram.php' directly (like put it in addressbar of browser), does it give you a 404 ?

Comment: Ohw... Are you sure flask can access files there? Apache (The A in LAMPP or XAMPP) cannot. I have my files in c:\xampp\htdocs\snippets\oct21 and the Apache server is using c:\xampp\htdocs as its 'server-root'. So... I start the server then ask for http://localhost/snippets/oct21/testFile.html - inside this file, I simply specify `action="callmyprogram.php"`.

Comment: The path in the 404 log and the path in the HTML are two different paths. How does one get turned into the other?

Comment: JohnCogan: yes it still gives me an error
enhzflep I don't know why flask couldn't. The files are all in the same folder, as well as the executable
@user253751 yes sorry I just edited my question with the right path

Comment: @enhzflep So you probably want it to go to localhost/snippets/oct21/callmyprogram.php then. Find out why it's going to localhost/callmyprogram.php. Is there an extra / somewhere?

Comment: @user253751 - Ahh, but the thing is, both files are in the same folder. I *want* it to goto localhost/snippets/oct21/testFile.html and localhost/snippets/oct21/callmyprogram.php, which it does. We're already in that folder when we request the html file, then, using relative paths, we get the php file from the same folder by not specifying one in the form's action attribute.

Comment: @enhzflep the 404 error shows it is going to localhost/callmyprogram.php for some reason, not localhost/snippets/oct21/testFile.html

Comment: @CamilleBouquet - It's a security feature basically. Without the concept of a 'web-root', you could ask for any file on the server, whether it's intended for public consumption or not. What if some sneaky bugger requested `/etc/passwd` !!? While the PHP file can get anything from , the html one cannot (nor can you specify any file via the url (excepting get/post parameters).

Comment: @user253751 - Then I guess it's a problem in the understanding of the OP with regards to how to use Flask. (I know virtually nothing of it, sticking to plain ole Apache server)